# Build BIND for DMZ Linux Server

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I have installed CentOS-6 server in our DMZ.
I have a public IP address which I will use for it.
Now, how should I set up its DNS in order to make it accessible from internet?
Is there any particular steps required for BIND in order to propagate the server to internet?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to configure you can use

http://www.howtoforge.com/bind-installation-on-centos

You should refer this previous thread

https://serverfault.com/questions/153690/why-arent-our-dns-records-propagating-out-into-the-internet

Answer (score 0):

There is no "propagation" so to speak; propagation is usually a term used to describe the delay in any updates made to the DNS when the old records have already been cached by some servers.

In this case, when you say that you want DNS on your server to be accessible to the Internet, you likely are planning to use BIND as an authoritative server, serving one or more zones. In that case, you will just have to ensure that TCP *and* UDP port 53 are open for incoming traffic from anywhere. You will set up BIND in a fairly standard manner. Just install BIND, add some zones to it.

On the zone that you're hosting, you will then refer to the hostname of the machine that you are running this BIND instance (and that hostname must be resolvable to an IP address), say ns1.myzns.com.